# Paint method casting - performance

Tags: java, graphics2d

I see a lot of people casting the Graphics type to a Graphics2d type inside their Paint method in an effort to have more functionality over the images they draw. Is it not possible cast the graphics type to a graphics2d type outside of the paint function? To me this screams performance issue because every time the paint method is called (i.e every frame) you are needlessly casting to a Graphics2D type every single time.

Also, does Java do any optimization whenever the paint method is called and the same screen is being drawn again? For example if you are only moving one element on the screen then you will generally only need to update that element. It seems java redraws and re-processes the whole screen every time the paint method is called. To me this all seems unnecessarily processing intensive.

Example code:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    AffineTransform transformer = new AffineTransform();
    transformer.translate(5,5);
    transformer.scale(2,2);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.setTransform(transformer);
    // draw to g2d.
}
```

Comment: Why would casting affect performance?

Answer (score 1):

You state:

> To me this screams performance issue because every time the paint method is called (i.e every frame) you are needlessly casting to a Graphics2D type every single time.

There is minimal cost to this, and so I wouldn't worry about it. Instead profile your program and concentrate on the bottle necks that the profiler shows you matter.

> Is it not possible cast the graphics type to a graphics2d type outside of the paint function?

No.

> Also, does Java do any optimization whenever the paint method is called and the same screen is being drawn again? For example if you are only moving one element on the screen then you will generally only need to update that element. It seems java redraws and re-processes the whole screen every time the paint method is called. To me this all seems unnecessarily processing intensive

I don't think so. What I've done is to 1) create a BufferedImage to display my static images, and then draw directly my dynamic images, and 2) if need be, limit the area being drawn by using the `repaint(...)` method overload that accepts a Rectangle.